# html5 word swap animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to swap the adjective in "This site is cool", using an array of words`[awesome, fun, useful, beautiful]`. I don't want to just swap it in one frame, I want to have a nice transition too. Maybe the new word can slide in from top, or it can zoom out and replace the old one. How do I implement it? Javascript? CSS3? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? There are a multitude of tutorials on this topic online.

Comment: I did google for half a hour, wasn't able to find it:( bad googling skills?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery-Effects like fadeIn.

HTML:

```
<div>This site is <div id="adjDiv" style="display:none"></div>.</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var adjPool = ["awesome", "fun", "useful", "beautiful"];
var adj = adjPool[Math.round(Math.random() * (adj.length-1))];
$("#adjDiv").text(adj);
$("#adjDiv").fadeIn();
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I need to hide the element first then fadeIn. But I got the idea. Maybe using the animate top offset will make it exactly what I want. Still wish there is a pure CSS3 or zoom in/out implementation like in impress.js But I guess that's too much for a small trick.